# How to concatenate two dimensional arrays of String in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I had below Structure -

```
    {
       String[][] array = null;
       array = getTable2C(Order order, v.get(i));
       return array;
    }
```

Now, I want to add a New code where I will be getting multiple 2-D String array & I want to return the whole concatenated 2-D String array at the end of the method.

```
    String[][] array = null;
    Vector v = getVectorFromSC(Order order);

    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
    {
       array = getTable2C(Order order, v.get(i));
       /*
       .
       . Some code to Concatenate multiple 2D array.
       . Something like, allArray = array +allArray;
       .
       */

    }
    return allArray;
```

How to Achieve this? I tried converting Array to Vector & again converting Vector to array(toArray() method of Vector) But, It Works for One Dimensional Array. I'm not sure how to use that for 2D Array.

Comment: What do you mean by concatenate? What is the format of your result?

Comment: what do you mean by concatenating 2-D array?
give an example !

Comment: I am receiving 2D array as result from method getTable2C(). Now as it is in loop, I will be getting multiple 2D arrays, I want to Concatenate them all & then, want to return the concatenated 2D array.

Comment: @AkshayBhore You're missing the point. You can concatenate them in several ways. Give an example of how you want to piece them together. Also, when you're done doing that, I bet you can figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:-

```
public String[][] yourMethod(){
String[][] array = new String[0][0];
    Vector v = getVectorFromSC(Order order);

    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
    {
       String[][] tempArray = getTable2C(Order order, v.get(i));

       array = concat(array,tempArray);

    }
    return allArray;
}

public String[][] concat(String[][] a, String[][] b) {
                String[][] result = new String[a.length + b.length][];
                System.arraycopy(a, 0, result, 0, a.length);
                System.arraycopy(b, 0, result, a.length, b.length);
                return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
  1->Vector<String[][]> allArray =  new Vector<String[][]>(); //DEfine a Vector that can hold 2D array
  2-> allArray.add(array); //Inside for loop keep adding each 2D array to vector
  3-> return allArray //Returns a vector which element is 2D array
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution using Java streams

```
String[][] twoDarr = new String[][] {
  {"1", "1", "1"},
  {"2", "2", "2"},
  {"3", "3", "3"}
};

String str = Arrays.stream(twoDarr).map(oneDArr -> Arrays.stream(oneDArr).collect(Collectors.joining())).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

It looks similar if you need to use it for non String arrays.

```
int[][] twoDarr = new int[][] {
  {1, 1, 1},
  {2, 2, 2},
  {3, 3, 3}
};

String str = Arrays.stream(twoDarr).map(oneDArr -> Arrays.stream(oneDArr).mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(Collectors.joining())).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Delimiter can be provided as parameter e.g. for commas via `Collectors.joining(",")`